# Calculate token amount minimums for Uniswap Router's removeLiquidity function

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, ethers.js

I'm trying to redeem my LP tokens with ethersJS and Uniswap's Router02 contract. How do I calculate the arguments `amountAMin` and `amountAMin` for the function linked below?

https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contracts/router02/#removeliquidity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `amountAMin` is parameter is present to prevent a sandwich attack on your transaction.

Lets say that, you have 1 share to a uniswap v2 pair which gives 1.1 ETH and 2200 DAI.

If you pass a value for e.g. `1 ETH` to the `amountAMin` when calling remove liquidity, then the Router contract will make sure that ETH sent to you is >= 1 ETH. And if there is a sandwich attack that changes price of ETH such that you now get only 0.9 ETH, then for safety the Router contract will purposely revert the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need token balances and total supply of the liquidity pair, let's me share - [example gist](https://gist.github.com/basileos/ece52f22ffc560b2978c4786685c3f06)

It uses real token addresses from Cronos mainnet.

Answer (score 0):

**amountAMin = liquidity*reserve0/totalSupply**

**amountBMin = liquidity*reserve1/totalSupply**

*Link is dead; so re-posted from [UniswapV2Router02.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Router02.sol#L103) screen shot below:*

[image]